# Populate combox with values from one cell

Tags: excel, vba

This is what i want to do:

Cell A1 value is: Cat, Mouse, Dog

I would like to populate a combo box in a userform with those values so a user could select either Cat, Mouse, or Dog.

Any help is much appreciated,Thanks in advance.

Comment: Recommend you add any code you've written to attempt the problem

Comment: I don't really know how to phrase my question, so when i try looking for examples their not related to my problem. Do you have some key words you could recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim animals() As String
Dim i As Integer

animals() = Split(Sheet1.Range("A1"), ", ")

With UserForm1.ComboBox1
    For i = 0 To Application.CountA(animals) - 1
        .AddItem animals(i)
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I edited my answer to a cleaner way that allows for list expansion.

Comment: Thanks SincereApathy, Yes the end goal will be to be able to adjust this for any number of values in a cell A1. A1 can have anywhere from 1 to 100 values in it.